# Partial grouping of a CSS selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I can't seem to find an answer to this so either it's not possible or i'm not wording my searches correctly - i'm hoping someone on here can help? :)

- I have some HTML (UL in my example) who's grand-parent (div) occasionally has a sibling and occasionally doesn't.  An example of this might be :

**No Sibling Example**

```
<section>
    <div>
        <div id="item">
            <ul>
                <li>Coffee</li>
                <li>Tea</li>
                <li>Milk</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**Sibling Example**

```
<section>
    <div id="sibling1">xxx</div>
    <div>
        <div id="item">
            <ul>
                <li>Coffee</li>
                <li>Tea</li>
                <li>Milk</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="sibling2">yyyy</div>
</section>
```

- I want to select the UL element only when it's grandparent (div) has siblings.

I was going to use the preceding selector.. something like

```
section div div#item ~ ul 
{
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

but I cant seem to get it to work.

Any guidance greatly appreaciated!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/m8b7oddj/1/ like this?

Comment: Hi Amit, thanks - that's kind of what I was trying to do.  Scimonsters response matches what I needed, as I needed to be able to not just run down the chain, but put a sibling selector in as my actual code is a bit more complex than my example so chaining down although works, isn't specific enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
section div~div div#item ul 
{
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

You need to select the parent div if it has a sibling. I'm not sure what your original selector was doing, but it was wrong.

Snippet with:

```css
section div~div div#item ul 
{
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div id="sibling1">xxx</div>
    <div>
        <div id="item">
            <ul>
                <li>Coffee</li>
                <li>Tea</li>
                <li>Milk</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="sibling2">yyyy</div>
</section>
```

Snippet without:

```css
section div~div div#item ul 
{
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div>
        <div id="item">
            <ul>
                <li>Coffee</li>
                <li>Tea</li>
                <li>Milk</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thankyou Scimonster, that's exactly what I was trying to do! For some reason my brain failed me this morning.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
section>div:not(:only-child) ul{
    background: red;
}
```

Here is a pen with two sections so you can see it works: http://codepen.io/vandervals/pen/qdqMvq

This has 2 advantages from the ~ method:

-It selects all ul from divs not only from one div.

-It is more readable.

Comment: I did not know the only-child selector existed, so thankyou for teaching me something new.  I agree that it is much more readable, so generally will be something I shall consider using.  In this instance however, I think Scimonsters post suits me better, each of the sibling divs has many things inside them, and I need to be quite specific here.  In your example <ul>yyyy</ul> is also highlighted, and to prevent this ( with my actual html not the stripped back version I posted) I feel it would end up more complicated in this instance.  A very good example though so thankyou.

Comment: The problem is that if you have another div, the other selector will highlight 2 as well.... If you want specificity you'd need a class somewere